# Try to use File.SAVEAS but get 404 error, because the size is big

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm using asp:fileupload control to upload my Picture files. So the user click on browse and select the file and click on upload and in event handler of upload button there is FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs () etc.

Everything works fine. Accept when for big file size. e.g. I've got a file (jpg) 5.5 MB. When I try to upload this file I get an the error below.

The strange thing is I the button upload file eventhandler I check the file size. If (intFileesize < intFileSizeLimit) etc.

But the strange thig is I remove all the code in Upload eventhandler for testing/debugging and I still get the error below. So the error occurs outside the Button handler. I mean 
the error cause is not by Fileupload.SAveAs etc.... So the question is how can I avoid this. I mean I have built restriction of 1 mb, but This code is not reached.

I don't have any problems with small sizes e.g. I could upload 400 kb w/o problem.

So the question is what is the cause for the big file size how can I solve this?

Other question is: Is there a tool or whatever to crop the filesize and upload? I mean even if they upload 6 mb picture, I should crop that to 50kb or whatever during upload. How to aproach this? maybe a 3rd party freeware?

ERROR I get after 2-3 seconds

**Oops! This page appears broken. HTTP 404 - File not found.**

Answer (score 0):

see `maxRequestLength` in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Comment: I checked my web.config -> maxRequestLength="32768"

Comment: I just tried on the IIS Server it self and the error is like this: Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.   <br/> •Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value. <br/> •Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxAllowedContentLength setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

Comment: I just dropped and dragged the code again in web.config, but the nice thing is I don't 404 error anymore... So that's good thing. The bad thing is it doesn't upload the file. The small sizes are still uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The default request size is likely being reached.  By default I believe ASP.NET supports a 4MB request size limit.  You can change this in your config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

The above example changes the request size to 20MB.  The thing to take into consideration is that HTTP was never really designed to handle large file uploads.  You may want to consider using an alternative, such as a Flash upload control...

**UPDATE**

For IIS7 you may need to update the configuration in the `system.webServer` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20480" />
```

IIS uses the same configuration system as ASP.NET, but because it may not be an ASP.NET handler being called, it has an additional setting for other content requests.

Comment: I checked my web.config and its 32 mb like this   (      <httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="32768" requestLengthDiskThreshold="32768" executionTimeout="99999" />)

Comment: I just tried on the IIS Server it self and the error is like this: Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.   <br/> •Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value. <br/> •Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxAllowedContentLength setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

Comment: Matthew, when I try to add <security> tag within <ystem.webserver> the intellisence is not promping the security word. I mean exepected in the intellisence window, but I even typed the code with closing tags and my  pages are not working, get 404 error when I click on hyperlinks. <configuration>  <system.webServer><security> 
        <requestFiltering> 
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20480" /> 
    </requestFiltering> 
</security> 
<modules>....</modules> etc.

Comment: I just dropped and dragged the code again, but the nice thing is I don't error anymore... So that's good thing. The bad thing is it doesn't upload the file. The small sizes are still uploaded.

Comment: Please keep in mind maxAllowedContentLength is measured in bytes, not kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have `maxRequestLength` set in the `<httpRuntime>` tag in web.config, it looks like you are hitting the IIS7 request filter.

Try adding this to your web.config:

```
<security> 
    <requestFiltering> 
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="33554432"/> 
    </requestFiltering> 
</security>
```

Depending on how your server is set up, you may also need to change the IIS configuration to allow you to set up request filtering at the application level rather than the machine level. Edit `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` and change:

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

To:

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Comment: I just dropped and dragged the code again in web.config, the nice thing is I don't error anymore (404) etc. The screen just flickers 1 time... So that's good thing. The bad thing is it doesn't upload the file. The small sizes are still uploaded. I've changed the requestfiltering from Deny to Allow. results is the same....

Comment: If you're not getting 404 anymore, it's likely to be something wrong with the code. Could you post some sample code?